# Press Multiple tabs on Web page using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a Web Element by press Tab, to find this element I need to press tab 15 times. I have this code to press Tab and Enter:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I searched on the internet and I found the following code using Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

N = 5  # number of times you want to press TAB

actions = ActionChains(browser) 
for _ in range(N):
actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.perform()
```

Or, since this is Python, you can even do:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser) 
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * N)
actions.perform()
```

Can you help me with it using java? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to press TAB followed by ENTER (both for 15 times) and is it the same element you have to press? Since if you TAB, your cursor moves to different element.

Comment: Do you *have* to press TAB 15 times? Is there really no other way to access the element? I'm guessing that if we had the HTML of that section of the page we could come up with a locator and skip the whole pressing TAB thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple methods for this action. Here I am using while loop:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
int x = 1;
// Exit when x becomes greater than 15
while (x<=15){
  driver.findElement("your locator here").sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
  // Increment the value of x for
  // next iteration
  x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
}
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

You can also find closest focusable element(like inputs, buttons..) and go to target element with less tabs:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].focus()", driver.findElement(closestElementLocator));
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
}
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

//You can also get the element
//WebElement targetElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
//targetElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```